# What's the correct way to log a user out of a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to provide a "log out" function in a Rails app. Should I do...

```
session.delete
```

or

```
reset_session
```

From reading the docs, both look like they could work. Does it matter? Or should I use something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `reset_session`, because it's part of the Rails API; whereas `CGI::Session#delete` is effectively an implementation detail which *might* change.